Boat efficiency
Recently I was watching a boat race for "all electric boats" that use solar power to drive the engine (no sail only electric motor with solar system). in this race all boats have to be less then 7 meter, it sould be DIY boat and the goal is to cross 500Km route along the sea shore
That got me curious - what would make a boat more efficient in water? or for a fixed solar system and driving motor - how can i improve the speed and distance that i can travel continiously?
My first guess would be having a boat that has very thin profile to reduce drag
and actualy most of the boats i saw in this class are catamarans to have thin floats but wide surface to mount the solar panels :) but here the similarity in this class of boats ends and Im not sure what would accualy be better?
Some boat builders explain building a fiberglass with foam boards would be better because of the reduced wight , on the other hand others say you should use plywood with fiberglass to have lower center of gravity and rigidity - wich one is better for a sea boat?
Some use parallel sides of the catamaran and some create slight angle - wich one would be better?
also what should be the aspect ratio and the distance between both sides?
Some use dipper prop and some more shallow? why? and how would that affect the boat?
Also some use bigger sigle rudder at the center together with big center board while others use 2 smaller rudders and center boards on each side of the catamaran
And are there any other other conciderations / tips?

Water line length is absolute key.  The longer the water line, the faster the boat.   This is a reason why boats are faster when they are healed over, because the water line length increases with heal.
